# How to setState in complex schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scenario

```
{
data:'',
skus: [
    { id: 1, ......}
    { id: 2, ......}
    { id: 3, ......}
]
api_first:'',
}
```

I have that schema and want to setState in somewhere skus on selected sku item and return changed item to original array

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code and your attempt to do it? Details about what may not be working?

Comment: i tried simple setstate but when i set state it change all value i use index but when i use index it doesn't collapse that particular item.and i cant share code due to confidential issue

Comment: @arslan See the updated answer at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
this.setState(produce(prevstate => 
prevstate.data.sku.obj="change"
))
```

this works for me

Comment: It is bad practice to mutate the state, prevent unexpected results by making a copy

Comment: but it works. and by the way i think its update an state?

Comment: Yes, this will work. However, in functional programming (which is reacts style) you should avoid mutating anything. This way, you can safely save references of objects without being scared of them changing later. If you do this be aware you cannot count on this invariant anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use functional setState and map:

```
const updateSku = (skuId, data) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    skus: prevState.skus.map(sku => {
     if (sku.id === skuId) {
       return {...sku, ...data}
     } // else
     return sku
    })
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

State immutability is important sometimes devs mutate states those are complex with multiple nested levels. You can always update state with simple javascript object update stratigy but I would suggest you to use [immerjs](https://github.com/immerjs/immer). It reduces the code and makes it much more cleaner and easy to understand what is going to change. It helps a lot in redux reducers where a complex state needs to be updated with mutation

Here is example

https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/example-setstate

```
/**
 * Classic React.setState with a deep merge
 */
onBirthDayClick1 = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        user: {
            ...prevState.user,
            age: prevState.user.age + 1
        }
    }))
}

/**
 * ...But, since setState accepts functions,
 * we can just create a curried producer and further simplify!
 */
onBirthDayClick2 = () => {
    this.setState(
        produce(draft => {
            draft.user.age += 1
        })
    )
}
```

Using immerjs, it will be

```
const updateSku = (skuId, data) => {
  this.setState(produce(draft => {
    const sku = draft.skus.find(s => s.id === skusId);
    Object.assign(sku, data);
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I have understood from your explanation is that when the SKU item gets changed you want to update the state Skus.
Here I've provided a solution for the same please try to relate with your example.

let's assume you have the following react component.

import React, { Component } from "react";

```
export class Sku extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: "",
      skus: [
        { key: "key1", value: "value1" },
        { key: "key2", value: "value2" },
        { key: "key3", value: "value3" },
      ],
      APIFirst: "",
    };
  }

  handleSkuChange = (data) => {
    this.setState(({ skus }) => {
      const newSkus = skus.map(sku => (sku.key === data.key ? { ...sku, ...data } : sku));
      return { skus: newSkus };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { data, skus, APIFirst } = this.state;
    const newSku = { key: 'key2', value: 'newSku' };

    console.log("states =>", data, skus, APIFirst);

    return (
      <button type="button" onClick={() => this.handleSkuChange(newSku)}>'Change sku'</button>
    );
  }
}
```

The handleSkuChange function will work like it,

```js
const skus = [
   { key: "key1", value: "value1" },
   { key: "key2", value: "value2" },
   { key: "key3", value: "value3" },
 ];
 
 const handleSkuChange = (data) => (
 skus.map(sku => (sku.key === data.key) ? { ...sku, value: "newValue" } : sku));
 
 const newSku = { key: 'key2', value: 'newSku' };
 
 console.log('old skus', skus);
 console.log('new skus', handleSkuChange(newSku));
```